# Map to servlet without servlet-mapping record

Tags: java, servlets

I'm developing a FrontServlet, so there is no need to map other Servlet. I use `getRequestDispatcher` for specific Servlet and I need some name to access it, to forward request, but without mapping's `url-pattern` I don't know how to do it.

Is there an ability to access the Servlet without being mapped in web.xml?

Comment: @kocko yes, it is. But there are no answer. I know how to do it in web.xml, and i also know how to do it with anotations. I need to avoid these records.

Comment: As @BalusC says in that post, that was a security hole on previous Apache implementations. That feature was deprecated and then removed

Answer (score 1):

You should have your servlet mapped to some name in order to invoke it programmatically, and this can be done:

- Either the old way with a `<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>` tag in the deployment descriptor file.
- With the **3.0** Servlet Spec with the annotation `@WebServlet`
- Using the `addServlet` method.

Then you will be able to chain your request to the your custom servlet.